# jupyter no se conecta al Servidor

Tags: python, sql, terminal, jupyter, anaconda

Al iniciar jupyter en Anaconda, me sale este mensaje: A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration. y al rato un error. Por mucho que intente reconectar el kernel no hay manera y no funciona. iba todo bien, no entiendo el motivo ni como solucionarlo a parte de desinstalar anaconda.

Hay alguna solucion?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no te conecta al kernel, puede ser que tornado te este dando problemas:

Intenta

```
"pip install --upgrade tornado==5.1.1"
```